# Salesforce deploy error flow: The processMetadataValues entry for TriggerType has an invalid value

Tags: deployment, visual-workflow

I am trying to deploy to a scratch org, but it fails on 4 flows with the following error:

> The processMetadataValues entry for TriggerType has an invalid value.

The current method of deploying is somewhat as such:

- pull master code from branch
- do modifications on a new branch
- push (modified) code to new branch, which triggers an automatic creation of a scratch org and deploys the code found in the new branch to it.

The deploy seems mostly ok (I can log into my scratch org), but several things have not been deployed, such as workflow tasks, etc. The last error I receive when deploying to the scratch org is only as previously stated.

It only happens on 4 flows (so, 4 similar errors); the thing is that the flows I'm trying to deploy either:

- have not been modified
- have been slightly modified but should still work
- all contain a valid triggertype as per documentation (onCreateOnly, onAllChanges, etc).

To ensure I'm not going crazier, I retrieved the existing flows as metadata from the stable master org (flows which work), and used those to deploy back to the scratch org: still the same errors on the same 4 flows.

Does anyone have an idea in which direction to look, or the cause of the issue? The flows have all been cloned and re-saved to ensure there no discrepancies regarding fields (they save with no errors).

Comment: Became an issue for two process builders in our system trying to create scratch orgs via sfdx after the upgrade to Winter '22. No solution yet.

Comment: Hi @frosty, did you manage to get this fixed ?  Did you, by any chance, deploy in a multilingual org ?